# Apache Shiro 1.4.0 initialization

Tags: java, apache, security, shiro

I installed Apache Shiro 1.4.0 and was following [this official tutorial](https://shiro.apache.org/tutorial.html) in order to set it up.

When I tried to initialize `SecurityUtils` with `SecurityManager` using this code from tutorial:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

I got a message that `IniSecurityManagerFactory` is deprecated now in favor of Shiro's `Environment`.

I can't find any tutorial that shows how to initialize Shiro using `Environment`, and its documentation doesn't help much:

> An Environment instance encapsulates all of the objects that Shiro
>   requires to function. It is essentially a 'meta' object from which all
>   Shiro components can be obtained for an application.
>
> An Environment instance is usually created as a result of parsing a
>   Shiro configuration file. The environment instance can be stored in
>   any place the application deems necessary, and from it, can retrieve
>   any of Shiro's components that might be necessary in implementing
>   security behavior.
>
> For example, the most obvious component accessible via an Environment
>   instance is the application's securityManager.

So, how do I use this new initialization mechanism?

Comment: FWIW, it seems that 1.4.0 hasn't been released officially yet.  At least, the website says that 1.4.0 is still in "early access mode".  So it's probably best to stick with 1.3.2, at least until the website is updated.  (`IniSecurityManagerFactory` is not deprecated in 1.3.2.)

Comment: FWIW, we are in Shiro 1.4.2 as of today, and the documentation is still outdated.

Comment: FWI still W, the same happens when following the [10 minute tutorial](https://shiro.apache.org/10-minute-tutorial.html) with Shiro 1.7.1.

Answer (score 7):

As of Shiro 1.5 there is now `BasicIniEnvironment`. Its [Javadoc](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.12.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/env/BasicIniEnvironment.html) suggests to create the `SecurityManager` like this:

```
Environment env = new BasicIniEnvironment("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = env.getSecurityManager();
```

You can then continue:

```
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

That being said, I think when using Shiro in a standard web application, I think one shouldn't be doing this on one's own, but instead configure the `EnvironmentLoaderListener` in the `web.xml` file:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

According to the [Javadoc](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.12.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/env/EnvironmentLoaderListener.html) this will use the [EnvrionmentLoader](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.12.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/env/EnvironmentLoader.html) and load the configuration from a `shiro.ini` by looking at the following locations:

1. /WEB-INF/shiro.ini
2. classpath:shiro.ini

Thus one can simply put the `shiro.ini` on the classpath, add Shiro will pick the config up itself.